# Countdown timers in a datagridview with .NET Framework 4.8 (C#7.3)

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, timer, .net-4.8

i would need some help with this problem.

I should insert several countdowns in Datagridview cells starting at 45 min, as shown in this scheme

visual aspect of the program:
[image: visual aspect of the program]

On the first column there are codes identified as "fix0001, fix0002, etc.," in the second column there is the "start date" of the code into the table, in the third column there is the date on which the code is to be removed (i.e., start date + 45 min), in the fourth column there is the timer that counts down (45, 44, 43, ....), and in the last column there is the status of the code (i.e., free or busy).

When the user enters any code (those in the first column), the program should record the start date, exit date, countdown, and code status in the various cells. Of course, as soon as the user enters the code, the countdown should start counting.

How can I put different countdown timers in different cells?

I sincerely thank anyone who decides to help me with this problem.

I am trying to rely on an external database (.txt or .csv file). Every time a user enters new data, the whole table is exported to a .txt or .csv file. The problem for me is the reading phase of the .txt file: I am trying to read the data from the database and do any calculations within the program. I don't know if I am on the right track.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to have one timer with a say 10 seconds interval and in its timer event handler recalculate all the countdown values?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine. How could I do that? Should I read the value in the "Output" column and subtract DateTime.now ?

Comment: Yes, give it a try and come back if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about countdown timers, specifically:

> **How can I put different countdown timers in different cells?**

It seems likely that for any given cell in your `DataGridView` the information that it needs can be calculated by knowing these three things:

- What is the input time?
- What is the output time?
- *What time is is **NOW**!?*

In an open ended way, you have asked for "help with this problem" so I will offer you one possible solution because I believe that using the `DataSource` property of `DataGridView` will help you simplify all of your interactions with this powerful UI control. This will also prove out the assertion that it's "sufficient to have one timer". Its purpose will be to provide continuous updated information for *what time is it now*.

[image: screenshot]

---

**Record `class` represents a Row**

Consider making a class that is a "model" for a row. Add public properties for values you wish to be shown in your `DataGridView`. Obtaining a result similar to what you have shown in your post is simplified by giving it the ability to update *itself* based on the current time.

```
enum State{ WAITING, ACTIVE, EXPIRED, FREE, }
class Record
{
    [DisplayName("ID code")]
    public string IdCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [DisplayName("Input time")]
    public DateTime? InputTime { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Output time")]
    public DateTime? OutputTime { get; set; }

    // Record calculates itself when the DataGridView refreshes.
    public string Remaining
    {
        get
        {
            if((InputTime == null) || (OutputTime == null))
            {
                State = State.FREE;
                return string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                // Are we inside the time window?
                if((InputTime <= now) && (now <= OutputTime))
                {
                    State = State.ACTIVE;
                    return (OutputTime - now)?.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")!;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(InputTime > now)
                    {
                        State = State.WAITING;
                        return (OutputTime - InputTime)?.ToString(@"hh\:mm")!;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        State = State.EXPIRED;
                        return "0";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public State State { get; private set; }
}
```

---

**Data Binding**

Using the `Record` class, assign the `dataGridView.DataSource` to a `BindingList<Record>()`. Now, instead of having to work with the UI control directly you can add or remove records by manipulating the Records list.

---

**Updates**

Whenever `Refresh` is called on the `DataGridView` the individual records will refresh their calculations. To ensure that this refresh occurs, use the method that loads the main form to perform the following:

- Auto-generate columns for the DGV.
- Add four items for testing purposes.
- Attach a timer event to update the DGV and the main form title bar.

Once this is done, the view will globally refresh one time per second, giving you a behavior similar to what you have described.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm() => InitializeComponent();
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        dataGridView.DataSource = Records;

        #region F O R M A T    C O L U M N S
        Records.Add(new Record()); // <- Auto-generate columns
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn init in dataGridView.Columns)
        {
            switch (init.Name)
            {
                case nameof(Record.IdCode):
                    init.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                    break;
                default:
                    init.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                    break;
            }
        }
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.IdCode)].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.InputTime)].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
        dataGridView.Columns[nameof(Record.OutputTime)].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm";
        dataGridView.CellPainting += onDgvCellPainting;
        Records.Clear();
        #endregion F O R M A T    C O L U M N S

        addTestRecords();

        // Because we're using System.Windows.Forms.Timer the
        // ticks are issued on the UI thread. Invoke not required.
        _seconds.Tick += onSecondsTick;
        _seconds.Start();
    }
```

Refresh the title bar and the DGV when the seconds timer fires event.

```
    BindingList<Record> Records { get; } =
        new BindingList<Record>();
    private void onSecondsTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = $"Main Form - {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        dataGridView.Refresh();
    }
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer _seconds = 
        new System.Windows.Forms.Timer { Interval = 1000 };
```

Convert the `State` property to a corresponding cell `BackColor`.

```
    private void onDgvCellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals(dataGridView.Columns["State"].Index) && (e.RowIndex != -1))
        {
            switch (Records[e.RowIndex].State)
            {
                case State.WAITING: e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue; break;
                case State.ACTIVE: e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightYellow; break;
                case State.EXPIRED: e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGray; break;
                case State.FREE: e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen; break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Add a few records so the behavior can be evaluated.

```
    // Simulated records for minimal sample.
    private void addTestRecords()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        // For testing, round to whole minutes;
        now = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, 0);

        Records.Add(new Record
        {
            IdCode = "fix0001",
            InputTime = now - TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            OutputTime = now - TimeSpan.FromHours(1) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        });
        Records.Add(new Record
        {
            IdCode = "fix0002",
            InputTime = now,
            OutputTime = now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        });
        Records.Add(new Record
        {
            IdCode = "fix0003",
        });
        Records.Add(new Record
        {
            IdCode = "fix0004",
            InputTime = now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            OutputTime = now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for your reply. I'm trying to write down your code. The problem is that is necessary C#8, and for some reason I have to use C# 7.3 (with .Net framework 4.7.2 or 4.8).

Comment: Thx for letting me know! Please add the [.net-4.8] tag to your post! I will check and see where the incompatibilities are and fix them.

Comment: Thank you! The problem appear on the line "return (OutputTime - now)?.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")!; In the Record class

Comment: I have uploaded a .NET 4.8 version to my GitHub repo. You can [clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/countdown-timers-in-dgv-4-8.git) it and give it a try.

Comment: The feature that caused the issue is called a [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) expressed as `!`.  Next time you encounter it, you'll know what to do :)